# Understanding the $\gamma$ rate of the SIR model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

Relating the SIER model, I am trying to understand the intuition of the $\gamma$ paramater. This paramater is the recovery rate. $\gamma$ is fixed and biologically determined. Some authors conider for USA:

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{18}$$

and then asserts that $\frac{1}{\gamma} = 18$ is to match an average illness duration of 18 days.

I can't understand how the inverse of 18 days can represent a recovery rate.

For example, if $\gamma = 5 \hbox{ recovered}/\hbox{day}$. How $1/\gamma = 1 \hbox{ day}/5 \hbox{ recovered}$ can represent a recovery rate?

Can someone explain to me what is the intuition behind this relationship between  illness days and recovery rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation lies in the exponential decay assumption of the process.

If $\gamma$ is the recovery rate, then the infection population behaves like $I'(t) = -\gamma I(t)$ (e.g. only focus on the removal/recovery rate for now). Solving the differential equation leads to $I(t) = I(0)e^{-\gamma t}$, which has a mean lifetime/removal time of $\frac{1}{\gamma}$, [see this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay). Hence the reason why the duration is the inverse of the removal rate.